# Pandas - Is there a way to make multiple operations at the same time in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code that will be executed more than 1.5 million times with different queries that are dynamically generated from a configuration file

I'm not trying to optimize the query conditions, I'm trying to see if rather than performing the query 3 times in different columns I can do the query once and get the same result

```
csv_file_profit = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\test_data.csv')

if query_str:
    profit_sum = csv_file_profit.query(query_str)['P/L'].sum()
    trans_count = csv_file_profit.query(query_str)['Tran ID'].count()
    atr_profit_sum = csv_file_profit.query(query_str)['Max ATR Profit'].sum()
```

Is there a faster way to get the same result?

Comment: what is `query_str`

Comment: It's a string that contains the query that is dynamically generated in each of the 1.5 million times it gets executed, that if clause is inside a loop and in each iteration the query_str gets assigned a different value. What I'm trying to see is rather than optimizing the queries that I cannot change is can I do the 3 operations in a single instruction? every line performs the same query 3 times just to get a different aggregation, the 2 sums and the count they all execute the same query just in different columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One improvement can be to compute filtered DataFrame **once** and then
perform further computation on this filtered result. Something like:

```
if query_str:
    filtered = csv_file_profit.query(query_str)
    profit_sum = filtered['P/L'].sum()
    trans_count = filtered['Tran ID'].count()
    atr_profit_sum = filtered['Max ATR Profit'].sum()
```

Execution time is about 50 % compared to your code, on a very limited
DataFrame (4 rows). For bigger DataFrame the difference should be bigger.